# Undefined function or method 'Ei' for input arguments of type 'sym'

Tags: matlab

```
syms x1 x2 x3 theta gamma beta rho miu sigma;
f=-(exp(i*x1)-1)*Ei(1, x2)/(i*x1);
```

Undefined function or method 'Ei' for input arguments of type 'sym'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `Ei` does either not exist or is not in your matlab path.

**Edit:** this function seems to be new in matlab 2011b, so if you are using an older version of matlab, the function won't be there -> error.

**Edit2:** do you have the **Symbolic Math Toolbox** installed?